# dd backup produces bigger image file

Tags: hard-drive, backup, dd, disk-image

I created a disk image with dd. The hard disk capacity is 2 GB. However, the image produced a 3.8 GB file.
I used:

```
dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 > /mnt/sd/disk0.img
```

(where mmcblk0 is a microSD card, with 3 partitions: 2 ext3 and 1 FAT32).

How can I test if it is done correctly?

Comment: Do you get the same result with `dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=/mnt/sd/disk0.img`?

Comment: Just to disconfuse me ;) `mmcblk0` is not mounted to `/mnt/sd`?!

Comment: Do you mean partition by "hard disk"? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12366515/difference-between-reading-from-dev-block-mmcblk0-and-dev-block-mmcblk0p1